# ImportError: cannot import name 'classproperty'

Tags: django

What is the solution of this error........

> from django.utils.decorators import classproperty
>
> ImportError: cannot import name 'classproperty'

Why this error shows. How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have this issue after 21 Oct 2019 that is because in this [PullRequest](https://github.com/django/django/pull/11945) `classproperty` were moved from `django.utils.decorators` to `django.utils.functional`.

You need to change your import statement or add some code to check what version of django are you using and from where to import the `classproperty`

```
try:
    # Django 3.1 and above
    from django.utils.functional import classproperty
except ImportError:
    from django.utils.decorators import classproperty
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your django version. This module is not there before django 1.9